# How to target select option that has selected value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is if the option contains this specific text it will show the other div but right now I'm not able to target only the option that has selected value on it.

I want to target the option if it has "selected"

```
<option class="wcumcs-option" value="USD" selected>$ USD</option>
```

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMnKp.png)

```
 if ($('select option:selected:contains("php")')) {
      $('.price.total-rental-price').show();
      $('h3.booking_cost').show();
    }
    if ($('select option:selected:contains("USD")')) {
      $('.price.total-rental-price-usd').show();
      $('h3.booking_cost_usd').show();
    }
    if ($('select option:selected:contains("GBP")')) {
      $('.price.total-rental-price-gbp').show();
      $('h3.booking_cost_gbp').show();
    }
    if ($('select option:selected:contains("CNY")')) {
      $('.price.total-rental-price-cny').show();
      $('h3.booking_cost_cny').show();

    }
    if ($('select option:selected:contains("SGD")')) {
      $('.price.total-rental-price-sgd').show();
      $('h3.booking_cost_sgd').show();

    }
    if ($('select option:selected:contains("CAD")')) {
      $('.price.total-rental-price-cad').show();
      $('h3.booking_cost_cad').show();

    }
    if ($('select option:selected:contains("AUD")')) {
      $('.price.total-rental-price-aud').show();
      $('h3.booking_cost_aud').show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var selected_value = $("#selector :selected").val(); 
  
    if(selected_value == "INR"){
       $(".show_select_value p span").html(selected_value);
        $(".show_select_value").show();
    }
    else{
       $(".show_select_value p span").html("");
        $(".show_select_value").hide();
    }

})
```

```css
.show_select_value{
  display: none;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
  <option value="USD">USD</option>
  <option value="INR" selected="selected">INR</option>
  <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
</select>

<div class="show_select_value">
  <p>Selected value is: <span></span></p>
</div>
```

**Hope this will help**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is this the thing you want and put onchange in select there.

```
var yourSelectId = document.getElementById("yourselectid");


var option= yourSelectId.options[yourSelectId.selectedIndex].value;

if(option == "USD"){
   $('.price.total-rental-price-usd').show();
   $('h3.booking_cost_usd').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps recommend using an event listener tied to the change event for this dropdown. Then depending on the selected option, perform the task you are intending.

```
document.getElementById("currencyDropDown").addEventListener('change',
  (event) => {
    switch (event.target.value) {
      case "USD":
        console.log({
          Message: "You have selected USD"
        });
        break;
      case "GBP":
        console.log({
          Message: "You have selected GBP"
        });
        break;
      case "NZD":
        console.log({
          Message: "You have selected NZD"
        });
        break;
    }
  }
);
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m58kyf0g/